# How can I send text value of a button to the server in ReactJS + ExpressJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, server-side, client-side

I'm having trouble sending button text value back to the server.

**The code of the button in client-side:**

```
{question.options?.map((option, index) =>
    <button key={index} className={styles.answer} onClick={() => guessHandling()}>{option}</button>)}
```

**The code of the onClick guessHandling function in client-side:**

```
const guessHandling = async (userGuess) => {
      const res = await axios.post('/api/guess', { userGuess });
        setStatusMessage(res.data.returnStatus);
};
```

**The code in server-side:**

```
app.post('/guess', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body.userGuess);   // <---- I RECIEVE "UNDEFINED" IN THE SERVER CONSOLE HERE. 
  res.send({
    returnStatus: "Guess Recieved"
  });
});
```

userGuess is undefined when I try to console.log it as seen above.

I also tried including .value, .innerText, .innerHTML... still does not work.

I tried using useState, but I do not know how to insert the button text into the state (which is the main problem of this question).

(Probably?) I'm missing something in the onClick functionality.. I would love to get some help on this problem.

Comment: You didn't actually pass the value into your call to `guessHandling`. Try `onClick={() => guessHandling(option)}`.

Comment: Problem fixed! Can't believe that was the issue...  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Elan Hamburger wrote in the comments,
Solution is simple:

You didn't actually pass the value into your call to guessHandling. Try:
onClick={() => guessHandling(option)}